# Is my expected value correct?

Tags: probability

I need to make sure if i answered this correctly(Ignore question two). Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the numbers of times you got $5$ or $6$, then:

$$P(X=n)=\binom4n\cdot\left(\frac26\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac26\right)^{4-n}$$

Hence:

- $P(X=0)=\frac{16}{81}$
- $P(X=1)=\frac{32}{81}$
- $P(X=2)=\frac{24}{81}$
- $P(X=3)=\frac{ 8}{81}$
- $P(X=4)=\frac{ 1}{81}$

Therefore your expected profit is:

$$-1\cdot\frac{16}{81}-1\cdot\frac{32}{81}-1\cdot\frac{24}{81}+49\cdot\frac{1}{81}=-\frac{23}{81}$$